# Getting ID of parent route consistently in child with observable

Tags: angular, angular-router

Assuming I have this route.

> /main/users/2/tables

How to make sure that the child route **tables** picks up a change in the param ID of parent route /users/**2** with an observable?

So in tables route component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.usersService.watchUser()
     .pipe(
       takeUntil(this.onDestroy),
       tap((user)=> {
         console.log(user['id']);
       })
     ).subscribe();
    
}
```

and in users/1 route:

```
    const userId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.usersService.currentUser$.next({id: userId});
```

How to make sure that tables observable is called once only and changes everytime ID changes in the users/1 route automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parent's params using the `ActivatedRoute` instance like this:

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.parent?.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params['id']) // do whatever you want with the params
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you. I figured out I can also use paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'. i'll accept your answer thanks

Comment: it will still call it twice for some reason

Comment: so when i leave change the user, it will call it twice. initialize will call once as expected

Comment: @dormant so it is fine now or still something wrong?

Comment: it works. but the observable in the /tables is getting called twice. even though it's being unsubscribed onDestroy

Comment: initially it will call once correctly. but then when switching from /main/users/2/tables to /main/users/1/tables route and vice versa it will start to call twice